# _GET adding variable to existing string

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting, get

Im stuck , I have a website which index's gamer profiles and now keeps a historic record.
Everythings implemented and working only when you manualy write the url out.
Folowing the link made by the form wont work because its `index.php?id=` and i then want to add `&date` onto this but `?date=` needs to be `&date=` from the form ontop of `index.php?id=` 

Normal user input normalyresults in somthing like:
**index.php?id=123456789**

which returns the users profile no problem
On that page i have "load historic data" drop down which shows dates of this profile to load dependant on the id input.

```
<form method='get' action='index.php?id=$data' >
```

Folowing the submit button on the page returns:

**index.php?id=123456789?date=112012**

however , The only way i can get this to work is to manualy change that **?** to a **&** between ID and DATE
For the life of me i cannot figure it out!

basicaly i need:
index.php?id=123456789 **?** date=112012
to be
index.php?id=123456789 **&** date=112012

So that when the page reloads i can see both ID and DATE
I think i can be done via post however i need it visible in the url idealy
Ive also tried:

```
<form method='get' action='$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']'>

<form method='get' action='id_$data'> (with a mod rewrite)
```

Comment: put the id with a hidden input. `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data?>">`

Comment: The action of the form wont be useful for page reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GET**

You can't use the get method for sending to a url already containing a get param as you will get mixed results from different browsers. You need to add them to hidden fields like this which will then get added to the URL when the form is sent:

```
<form method='get' action='index.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php print $data; ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='date' value='112012' />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

**POST**

If you need to set the form method to post, while containing get params in the url it needs to be done like this:

```
<form method='get' action='index.php?id=<?php print $id; ?>&date=112012'>
<input type='text' name='message' value='this is in POST, the other params are in GET' />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

**SECURITY**

Do not do this:

```
<form method='get' action='$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']'>
```

[Reason why not](http://coding-talk.com/f19/why-is-%24_server%5Bphp_self%5D-unsafe-for-use-13998/)

Comment: Sorted , thanks VBAssassin that made sense to me, and is working. I can do everything else i just suck with forms as i suck with them... Also thanks to everyone else who answered. Now i understand how that worked i feel so dumb!

Comment: Your welcome, i just added the security bit at the bottom incase you missed it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace() to replace all ? into &

```
   $replacedstring = str_replace ( '?' , '&' , '$stringtobereplaced' )
```

[str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

However it is beter to look up in the code and see how the '?' is added to the string and replace it there.

Best regards,
kasper

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before... and here's my solution. Build a string of parameters all with the ampersand.

`$parameters = "&id=9&date=tomorrow&x=y";`

then I just replaced the first ampersand with a question mark.

`$correct_string = "?" . ltrim($parameters, '&');`